# Opentext - Content Server - Update SQL Table from Form

Tags: content-management-system, opentext

What is the procedure to update a table on the SQL Database from a Content Server Form?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Form Template object, then manage its relationable table (using its context menu) and create or link an SQL table.

Then you create a form for that template, pick the wanted submission mechanism and you are done. Using that form you have CRUD capability on that SQL table.